# What's the song thay plays in episode 13 when Eren takes a big rock to the hole in wall?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

There's a song in *Attack on Titan* season 1 episode 13 at about 13:00 when Eren takes a big rock to the hole in the wall.

What's the name of the song, and where can I legally buy or listen to this song?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The song title is "Call Your Name" (track #15) with vocals by mpi & CASG.

You can buy [the Audio CD at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAL4LEI) and it has the full OST of *Attack on Titan*.